# What is the scalable way to implement Total View Count, Month View Count, Week View Count

Tags: php, algorithm, caching, pageviews

I am looking for scalable way to implement total number of view, total number of view in the last 30 days (month), and the total number of view in the last 7 days (week). **Accuracy is not important**.

This is what I currently do

I am using memcached to temporary store the number visitor on each page. For example: I would store three fields: **number of view after the last update to database**, the last updated **DateTime**, and **JSON format data that have list of view count each day for the last 30 days**. For each new visit, we will  increase the number of view and as well increase the number of view in JSON format of the current date.

When **number of view after the last update to database** goes over 100 views, we will update our database. First increase the total view, then sum the last 7 days view from our JSON format and update in week view counter field, then sum the last 30 days view and update in month view counter field. Lastly, we will also update the JSON data into database as well, in case, memcached failed or server crashed.

Comment: i would outscore to google analytics.

Comment: What Dagon said.  If your not associating the views with the user session or other good meta data might as well just use Google analytics or your own server access logs.  Scales very well.

Comment: We do have Google Analytics, but we need those number so that user can sort our article by hottest (most viewed article).

Comment: use the api to grab the page views once a day and store that locally